# How can I get the value of an element onClick in React and use it as condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner in react, I have a calendar with one month that I've created using `<table></table/>` tag, The concept that I'm working on is when I click on a random day, I want to create an event and submit it, but if there is already an event inside this day I want to show the overview of the event that has been created in this day(like google calendar).

I've created a function `handlerClick` to toggle the form to create an event and also a function to submit an event. but I didn't know how to write the logic of giving the user the right the create only one event on a specific day in the calendar or if there is an event, I want to show the overview of that existed event.

<-- My Calendar Compoennts-->

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Day from './Day';


const Calendar = () => {
    const [eventForm, showEventFrom] = useState(false);
    const [eventName, setEventName] = useState("");
    const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([]);
    console.log(eventList);
    
    //Submit function
    const submitHandle = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      if(!eventName) {
          alert("Please Enter a name for Your Event")
      }
      else {
        const newEvent = {id : new Date().getTime().toString(), title: eventName}
        setEventList([... eventList, newEvent]);
        setEventName("");
      }
    };

    //Show Event Function
    const handleEvent = () => {
      showEventFrom(!eventForm)
    }

    
    return (
        <>
      <table className="table-calendar" >
        <tr>
        <th colspan="7">January</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <th>S</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>S</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <Day day="1" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="2" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="3" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="4" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="5" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="6" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="7" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <Day day="8" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="9" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="10" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="11" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="12" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="13" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="14" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <Day day="15" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="16" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="17" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="18" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="19" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="20" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="21" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <Day day="22" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="23" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="24" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="25" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="26" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="27" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="28" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <Day day="29" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="30" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        <Day day="31" onClick={handleEvent}/>
        </tr>
      </table>

      {eventForm ? (<form className="event-form" onSubmit={submitHandle}>
          <h3>Create an event</h3>
          <input type="text" 
                 placeholder="Event Name" 
                 className="event-name" 
                 value={eventName}
                 onChange={(e)=> setEventName(e.target.value)}/>

           <div className="btn-container">
            <button type="submit"
                    className="btn">Submit</button>
            <button className="btn">Delete</button>
           </div>
      </form>) : ""}
    </>
    )
}

export default Calendar;
```

<-- My Day Components-->

```
import React from 'react'

const Day = ({day, onClick}) => {
    return (
        <>
        <td onClick={onClick}>{day}</td>    
        </>
    )
}

export default Day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnClick` function sends information about the component it's used in by default as a param of the function you choose, `getData` in this case.
So, you can access this function param by using an arrow function like this:

```
import React from 'react'

getData = (e) => {
    // find data you need
    console.log(e);
}

const Day = ({day, onClick}) => {
    return (
        <>
        <td onClick={((e) => this.getData(e))}>{day}</td>    
        </>
    )
}

export default Day
```

Comment: Thank you but your answer is not clear, Can you explain more?

Comment: I write onClik={Onclik} in my date component so in my calendar component I pass a function handlerClick to it to display my form to create an event, by using your code I will not have this possibility, I've written your code is giving me an error of data is not defined!!